# How can I prevent LaTeX to modify the font after using /times?

Tags: fonts, latex, ascii, symbols, multiplication

I've been  struggling with the /times option in LaTeX. I'd like to use the '×' character, but since I can't write it "raw" in the text I have to use /times to write it. The problem is I want to output this :

Générer une grille de taille N×M :

But it outputs instead
Générer une grille de taille N× *M*

here is the codes I tried :

```
\paragraph{Générer une grille de taille N{\times}M :}
```

and

```
\paragraph{Générer une grille de taille N\times M :}
```

but all of them result in my "M" being in italic and it changes its font and I 
don't know how to prevent that... Any solution ?

P.S. : I'm sorry if there are spelling mistake, I'm still learning english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

> N $ \times $ M

Comment: Thanks ! Any way it doesn't include spaces tho ? If not it's okay that's still nice :)

Comment: Just delete the spaces in between if you dont want them. N$\times$M is with no spaces, add spaces on the outside of the $\times$ if you want more.